# Split text file into chunks of lines

Tags: bash, split

From a bash shell, how can I split a text file into chunks of exactly 3000 lines each?  Of course, the last chunk can be smaller.

Is that possible, or should I use a more robust language to do that?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

http://www.computerhope.com/unix/usplit.htm

`split`, with option `-l 3000`, will do what you want.

Comment: How obvious :D  Thanks!

Comment: @Rahul Yes, I will, but SO makes you wait 15 minutes or so.